Firebird 5.0 I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation
The output I get when trying to bring up my project is as follows: The database example.fdk has been restored to the desktop by Firebird as BERLINLOCALDATABASE.FDB.
Error message:FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "BERLINLOCALDATABASE.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "BERLINLOCALDATABASE.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
I want my project to go live.
The ConnectionString is correct.
I have enough space on disk.

Please provide the full error, as it usually also include what the error was (e.g. "The system cannot find the file specified."). Also provide a [mre], like are you using embedded, or connecting through the server, and where the file is really located (you say desktop, do you mean it is on the desktop of your user profile?). It sounds like you're trying to connect to the database file BERLINLOCALDATABASE.FDB which is a relative path, which may mean Firebird is trying to find the database in a different location than you think. Specify the absolute path.

Also, telling is "The ConnectionString is correct." is not very useful, because if it were, you'd be able to connect.

Connection string is obviously incorrect because error message doesn't include path to desktop thus the file is looked for in the current directory.

The ConnectionString is correct because it's the same path I've used in other projects that are working fine. Is there a specific location specified within the Firebird file? Additionally, I've noticed the following situation: when the database is connected, the project doesn't start up; however, when the database is disconnected, the project starts up without any errors.

That sounds like you're trying to use an embedded connection while the Firebird is configured in SuperServer mode, then only one application can connect. You need to provide a lot more information: 1) the location of the file, 2) the actual connection string, 3) the full exception, 4) which user is running your application
